# Alertmanager SMS alert to custom provider

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

We do have an SMS gateway from our local provider that allows sending SMS with the following URL format:
[https://prosms.dds.a1.net/mssms/rest/sendSms.do?username=USERNAME&password=PW&recipients=012345678&msgtext=TEXT"](https://prosms.dds.a1.net/mssms/rest/sendSms.do?username=USERNAME&password=PW&recipients=012345678&msgtext=TEXT%22)

I managed to send a default text with an alertmanager webhook, but I have no idea how to send an actual alert text - if that is even possible with that API. I read that first of all, it needs to be able to deal with JSONS, and I don't know if it does that, but I also don't know how to test it.

Can someone help me out here?

Answer (score 1):

AlertManager webhook sends the alert information via the request body.

Unfortunately, it doesn't have an option to map it to URL parameters such as in URL format example.

You'll have to run a different service that will map these bodies to URL params.

I'm not sure if there are services that do this. In my organization, we wrote a simple HTTP service to handle it.

It was working along the line so of:

1. Expose HTTP end point for handling alerts
2. Construct URL from request body
3. Send POST request to the new URL